# Text is not centered

Tags: html, css

I found lot of codes how to center text, but nothing works. Somewhere must be error in my code. I try to center `h1.main` to the middle of the page. 50% top and 50% left. But always are there some pixels out from both sides. It doesn't center text.

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(){$('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open',500);$(this).toggleClass('open');})
$('.menu-link').click(function(){$('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open',250);$('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('open');})
$(function($){$('a').on('click',function(e){var $anchor=$(this).attr("href");var $hrefStart=$anchor.substr(0,1);if($hrefStart=="#"){$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$($anchor).offset().top},1500,'easeInOutExpo');e.preventDefault();}else{window.location.href=$anchor;}});})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');

body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
 
}

.container {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

}
header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block; 
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
 
}

.site-nav {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 top: 100%;
 right: 0;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
}
.site-nav--open {
 height: 100vh;
 opacity: 100;

}
.site-nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 
}
.site-nav li {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;

/* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}
.site-nav li:last-child {
/* border-bottom: none; */
}
.site-nav a {
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #9E9E9E;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 2em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 z-index: 99999;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
 
 color: white;
}
.menu-toggle {
 position: fixed;
 padding: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 right: .75em;
 top: .5em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 background-color: #2ecc71;
 height: 3px;
 width: 1.75em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger::before {
 
 transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.hamburger::after {
 transform: translateY(3px);
 
}


.open .hamburger::before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
 transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
 
}
.open .hamburger {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#particles-js {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 
}
#about {
 height: 100vh;
 
 
}
#portfolio {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: blue;
 
}
#contact {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: red;
}
h1.main {
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 left: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 5rem ;
}
h2 {
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 5%;
 font-size: 2em;
  
}
a.logo {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #2ecc71;
}
span.home {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 1%;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .site-nav a {
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Doplniť neskôr">
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#particles-js" class="logo"><h1 class="logo">Lorem <span>ipsum</span></h1></a>
        <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#particles-js">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </header>
<div id="particles-js">
<h1 class="main">Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
<span class="home">Home</span>
<div id="about">
         
</div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>

<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `)(jQuery);` should be `(jQuery));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to below code

```
h1.main {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

`transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` will center the element wrt to its own position, as the pivot/anchor of the element is to the top-left.

This works by pushing itself left and top by 50% of its own length and height,
thus centering the element

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
$('.menu-link').click(function() {
  $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 250);
  $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('open');
})
$(function($) {
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $anchor = $(this).attr("href");
    var $hrefStart = $anchor.substr(0, 1);
    if ($hrefStart == "#") {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor).offset().top
      }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      window.location.href = $anchor;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');
body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.site-nav--open {
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 100;
}

.site-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-nav li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  /* border-bottom: none; */
}

.site-nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  color: white;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .75em;
  top: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#particles-js {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#about {
  height: 100vh;
}

#portfolio {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

#contact {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

h1.main {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

a.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2ecc71;
}

span.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .site-nav a {
    padding: 2em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Doplniť neskôr">
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#particles-js" class="logo">
        <h1 class="logo">Lorem <span>ipsum</span></h1>
      </a>
      <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#particles-js">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="particles-js">
    <h1 class="main">Lorem ipsum</h1>
  </div>
  <span class="home">Home</span>
  <div id="about">

  </div>
  <div id="portfolio"></div>
  <div id="contact"></div>

  <script src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

let me explain the issue with your code, since you need the text to be center, hence can get rid of `left: 50%` and add `left:0; width: 100%`. these two updates fixes your issue, please check the below working snippet, hope it helps :)

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function () { $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500); $(this).toggleClass('open'); }) $('.menu-link').click(function () { $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 250); $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('open'); })
$(function ($) { $('a').on('click', function (e) { var $anchor = $(this).attr("href"); var $hrefStart = $anchor.substr(0, 1); if ($hrefStart == "#") { $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $($anchor).offset().top }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo'); e.preventDefault(); } else { window.location.href = $anchor; } }); })(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');
body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',
  sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.site-nav--open {
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 100;
}

.site-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-nav li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  /* border-bottom: none; */
}

.site-nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  color: white;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .75em;
  top: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#particles-js {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#about {
  height: 100vh;
}

#portfolio {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

#contact {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

h1.main {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

a.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2ecc71;
}

span.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .site-nav a {
    padding: 2em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#particles-js" class="logo">
      <h1 class="logo">Lorem
        <span>ipsum</span>
      </h1>
    </a>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-link" href="#particles-js">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="particles-js">
  <h1 class="main">Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
<span class="home">Home</span>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy fix, you just need to update your 2 code blocks in your CSS. The problem was your container `#particle-js` is not centering your h1 vertically. So I just set its `display: flex` and using `align-items` property I have aligned it to vertically center.

```
#particles-js {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

h1.main {
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5rem ;
}
```